# How to put the rows of a query to the bottom if a column has a certain value ordered by another value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table products with 3 columns:
- id_product
- quantity_in_stock
- product_name

I want to have all the rows ORDERED BY product_name with quantity_in_stock at the bottom of my result if it's = 0.

I tried this query but it doesn't work:

```
(SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE quantity_in_stock != 0
ORDER BY product_name ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE quantity_in_stock = 0
ORDER BY product_name ASC)
```

Maybe there is a simpler way to do that but it's monday! ;)

Comment: ORDER BY quantity_in_stock = 0?

Comment: Sorry, I changed now my question: I want it ordered by product_name. With that query I actually can separate products by quantity_in_stock but they don't show ordered by product_name!

Comment: Come on. See if you can figure out how to fix that yourself. Or just wait six seconds and have it all handed to you on a plate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` can contain an arbitrary expression, so you can evaluate those which `= 0` and assign them a higher value which sorts later:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
ORDER BY 
  /* If quantity_in_stock is 0, assign a 1 otherwise 0. The ones sort after 0 */
  CASE WHEN quantity_in_stock = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
  /* Then sub-order by name */
  product_name ASC
```

Because of MySQL's boolean evaluation returning 1 or 0, you can simplify this as below. It won't work in every RDBMS though:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
ORDER BY
  /* Will return 0 (false) for quantity_in_stock <> 0 and 1 if true */
  (quantity_in_stock = 0) ASC,
  product_name ASC
```

Beware though, if `quantity_in_stock` is not indexed, query performance could be affected negatively by this.

Comment: or you can `order by ABS(SIGN(quantity_in_stock))` in this case

Comment: @valex Yes that would be clever and portable.

Comment: @valex should I change (quantity_in_stock = 0) to ABS(SIGN(quantity_in_stock)) ?

Comment: @alessandroweb Yes you can change that, but it isn't really necessary. Either of the other two will work for your need, and the first one above is the most common pattern for this kind of conditional ordering.

Comment: @alessandroweb The best way is to use the first one with CASE.

Comment: @valex ascending is default if i m not wrong, then is it mandatory to use ASC.Sorry to ask such silly question,i m new to sql.

Comment: @AndroidKiller No, it isn't mandatory to use `ASC`. Good to be explicit though. Just noticed I was missing an `END` keyword on the `CASE`.